# I want to launch my Background Media Player UWP app as an alarm

Tags: uwp, alarm, background-media-player

I built a Background Media Player UWP app (targeted specifically at Anniversary Update) that plays music from my personal collection in a manner that I want using playlists defined in the app.
I would like the ability, in my app, to create and manage alarms (day, time, recurrence, etc...) and associate each with a specific playlist defined in the app and have the alarm wake the app and begin to play the appropriate playlist.
The docs suggest, when trying to create an alarm, using a Toast notification but I can't see how to get the notifications to accomplish my goals.
Any ideas?

Comment: You mean you want to set notification to start your Background Media Player?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like the ability, in my app, to create and manage alarms (day, time, recurrence, etc...) and associate each with a specific playlist defined in the app and have the alarm wake the app and begin to play the appropriate playlist.

It is not possible to awake any app without user interaction(Click or Touch).

Toast Notification can be used for Alarm, and it can play custom Audio using Audio tag. See [ToastNotification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-adaptive-interactive-toasts?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#audio).
But it can't play a playlist. So it is not a feasible scenario.